# Copy the stack trace text from XCode Crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have a Stack Trace for my released app in Xcode (Organizer > Crashes). I want to e-mail the trace to a colleague but I am unable to copy/paste the trace.

Is this possible? Am I just missing something very obvious as I am not that familiar with OSX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can right click on the crash -> Open in Finder. In the Finder you will see a .xccrashpoint package.

You can e-mail your colleague this package or again right click -> Show Package Contents.

In this package you will find your actual .crash logs (which you can view in any editor & therefore easily copy your crashlog) under DistributionInfo->All->Logs

Comment: It doesn't answer how can you get a text version of a stacktrace.